# Perfect match algorithm in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-algorithm

I try to implement a [perfect match](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) algorithm in `cypher` to find constricted sets (pairs) in a weighted bimodal network.

For example, there are employees and a set of tasks they can do. An employee can do more than one task. Each task has a priority which in this case is an edge weight. I would like to get the optimal task-employee matches considering the priority. I imagine that I should iterate over the two node sets ordered by `degree x priority` values but I don't know how.

I've gone through the list of algorithms incorporated in Neo4j at the moment and couldn't find anything alike. I wonder if there any implementations of the algorithm or anything close to it? I think it might be useful to have one in Neo.

Answer (score 0):

I have just written a couple of blog posts that might help you.

https://medium.com/@nsmith_piano/the-perfect-dorm-room-assignment-exploring-the-bipartite-matching-problem-with-neo4j-c59ade420acb

https://medium.com/@nsmith_piano/a-market-for-matches-finding-prices-with-neo4j-71ab085f8cd2

Here's cypher that I used to match "student" and "room" nodes.

```
CALL apoc.periodic.commit(
"MATCH (s:Student)
WHERE NOT s:Matched
WITH s LIMIT 1
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(s, {relationshipFilter:'INTERESTED_IN,MATCHED_WITH,INTERESTED_IN',
nodeFilter:'Room|Student', 
minLevel:1, 
maxLevel:7, 
filterStartNode:false}) 
yield path AS alternatingPath
WITH s, alternatingPath,
nodes(alternatingPath)[-1] AS lastNode,
relationships(alternatingPath) as rels
WHERE lastNode:Room
AND NOT lastNode:Matched
WITH s, lastNode, rels
LIMIT 1
SET lastNode:Matched
SET s:Matched
WITH s, rels
UNWIND rels AS rel
CALL apoc.refactor.setType(rel, CASE TYPE(rel) WHEN 'MATCHED_WITH' THEN 'INTERESTED_IN' ELSE 'MATCHED_WITH' END) YIELD output
RETURN count(*)")
```